# SQL Query help needed in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which has records of `MYSQL_DISK_USAGE` of different servers at different intervals of time.

**Example :** For every server A,B,C,D... we get the data of `MYSQL_DISK_USAGE` for every minute.

We need to extract the `LATEST VALUE` of `MYSQL_DISK_USAGE` for every server.

Comment: how are you defining latest value, do you have a time column

Comment: Yes i have a time column in the table.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

just do it?

```
select * from 
(
    select server, MYSQL_DISK_USAGE, 
    row_number() over(partition by server order by yourcolumntime desc) rang
    from yourtable
) tmp
where rang=1
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering `YourTable` would have a time column storing time of that `MYSQL_DISK_USAGE`

```
SELECT Server_Name, MAX(Time) [Latest_Time]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Server_Name
```

Comment: We cannot use MYSQL_DISK_USAGE in select as this is not used in group by.